# Swift Как преобразовать массив в словарь

Tags: swift

Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой красивый лаконичный вариант преобразования массива в словарь? Что меня интересует:к примеру есть массив строк array = [“1”, “2”, “3”, “4”] нужно из него сделать словарь dict = [“1”:”2”, “3”:”4”]. Спасибо!

Comment: задача проста и решается циклом просто с добавлением двойки вместо единицы в цикле к индексу. В чем конкретно проблема возникла и где код попыток это сделать?

Comment: С циклами проблем нет. Делал с помощью цикла for enumerated разбивал массив по индексам и делал с ними что хотел, но тут наткнулся на такой пример получения словаря из массива как Dictionary(uniquekeywithvalue:) и такие операторы как zip, map, reduce. Но я так и не смог найти пример который бы решал таким образом мою задачу.

Comment: мап необходим для перевода и обработки информации в рамках одного количества элементов. Например - добавить к каждой строке что-то. Или конвертировать каждый элемент во что-то другое и получить то же количество элементов. Редьюс это ближе к рекурсии или циклу который перебирает что-то в переменную-аккумулятор. Зип уже не помню. Вроде неким способом обьединяет несколько Result-ов. Вобщем цикл с правильной обработкой всех ситуаций - все твое.

Comment: С помощью zip я объединял два массива в словарь первый- key, второй- value при условии что key будут unique. Пробовал так dict = Dictionary( uniqueKeyWithValue: zip(array[{$0%2=1}], array[{$0%2=0}])) но получал просто кучу ошибок, что так нельзя делать. Потому решил обратиться с вопросом, что может есть подобные решения- в одну строчку, делая код более лаконичным.

Comment: Сделай через цикл + сделайай метод расширения на массив. Вот и все. Твоя задача достаточно уникальна что бы не было стандартного красивого способа ее решить в одну строку.

Comment: Ясно. Тогда так и сделаю. Спасибо большое за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант. Но непонятно, что делать с нечетным количеством элементов

В примере - откидывается "лишний" четный элемент

```swift
let result = arr.enumerated()
    .filter { $0.offset % 2 == 0 && $0.offset < arr.count - 1 }
    .reduce(into: [String: String]()) {
        $0[$1.element] = arr[$1.offset + 1]
}
```

Comment: Да, это работает. Спасибо. Я получаю массив с заведомо четным количеством элементов, тут проблем нет.